# Overriding methods seem don't work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I have 3 routes

```
POST /api/v1/items/ controllers.Application.update
POST /api/v1/items/:item_type controllers.Application.update(item_type: String)
POST /api/v1/items/:item_type/:id/ controllers.Application.update(item_type: String, id: Int)
```

and 3 corresponding actions for them. And one error:

```
[error] /my_app/conf/routes:3: method update is defined twice
[error]   conflicting symbols both originated in file '/home/alex/my_app/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/routes_reverseRouting.scala'
[error] POST /api/v1/items/:item_type/:id/ controllers.Application.update(item_type: String, id: Int)
```

Please notice that should not be any default value for the parameters that is why I need these actions to be separated.

Comment: Could you use different names for your `update` methods? I think the issue comes from play not liking overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In play methods are called by name. Parameters are omitted. Name of method has to be unique. You can not have the same name for controllers (if you have in two packages)

Please use default parameters:

```
POST /api/v1/items/ controllers.Application.update(item_type: String = "", id: Int = 0)
POST /api/v1/items/:item_type controllers.Application.update(item_type: String, id Int =0)
POST /api/v1/items/:item_type/:id/ controllers.Application.update(item_type: String, id: Int)
```

Comment: You can either write 3 methods - or you can set default values in routes and call only `controllers.Application.update(item_type: String, id: Int)`. Other method can be removed.